# Creating a PNG source from data in memory

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8

Situation:
I am reading a PNG file, encoded with base64 from a server (JSON Format). Works fine. 
There is NO direct URL to the ressource (just like: http:... / image.png or simuliar), so i read the data (which is part of a JSON object), decode in from the base64 Encoding and store it in a byte[].

Want i want: Display this PNG on a certain page ( like:

```
ImageOnPage.Source = myPNG;
```

)

I cant find a way to make PNG-data to a bitmap. With jpegs i could do something like

```
 using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data, 0, x, true, true)) {
            var wbp = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
            wbp.LoadJpeg(stream);
            profileImage.Source = wbp;
        }
```

(sorry, code not testet)

I tried to look around and find the [PNG Writer Library](http://toolstack.com/libraries/pngwriter) - but i still didn't find a way to do something to convert my internal PNG to a useable Bitmap for Setting the Image.Source.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I guess that you should save the image to a temp location to display in the page.

Comment: Or, embed directly the Base64 string in the image's src: http://sveinbjorn.org/news/2005-11-28-02-39-23/Embedded-image-data-in-HTML-documents.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hints. I changed it in the way, that i store the Image in a temp Location in the isolatedStorage. THis costs some Performance, but in this case, it is still ok.